# Is it better to iterate over documents to get the minimum value of field or use aggregate function in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection of items.

```
[
   {
       'item': ... ,
       'price' : ...
   }
   .
   .
   .
]
```

I need all the documents that have the 'item' : 'A',  along with the minimum price of all such items. So, in general, if the number of such documents of item "A" can be at max 2000, is it better to find the minimum price by iterating over the retrieved documents or use the aggregate function in mongodb (if i use aggregate, i will essentially be going over the documents twice, once by using the .find({..}) and once by using .aggregate(). Or is there a way to combine both retrieving and getting the minimum.

**EDIT [Added Explanation]**
For example, if I have 3 documents

```
[
   {
       'item': 'A' ,
       'price' : 30
   },
   {
       'item': 'B' ,
       'price' : 40
   },
   {
       'item': 'A' ,
       'price' : 20
   }
]
```

I want the output to be similar to:

```
[
   {
       'item': 'A' ,
       'price' : 30
   },
   {
       'item': 'A' ,
       'price' : 20
   },
   'min_price' : 20
]
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to write the query to get minimum `price`:

**(1) Aggregation:**

The aggregation query runs on the server and returns the result (minimum price) to the client (the `mongo` shell from where you run the query). That is the result in ***one action***.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  $match: { item: 'A' },
  $group: { _id: null, min_price: { $min: "$price" } }
)
```

**(2) Not so efficient way:**

The `find` query runs on the server and gets all the documents matching the query filter `{ item : 'A' }` to the client (`mongo` shell). In the shell you iterate (loop) over the returned documents to figure which document has the minimum price. That is ***multiple actions*** - query on the server, a network trip back to the client, and processing on the client.

```
db.collection.find( { item: 'A' } )
             .toArray()
             .map(obj => obj.price)
             .reduce((acc, curr) => (acc < curr) ? acc : curr)
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]
The aggregation gets all the documents with minimum price:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { item: "A" } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
         min_price: { $min: "$price" },
         docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
     } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          docs: { 
             $filter: { input: "$docs", as: "doc", cond: { $eq: [ "$$doc.price", "$min_price" ] } } }
      }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$docs" 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" } 
  }
] ).pretty()
```

Comment: Your first method using aggregation gives me the minimum price pertaining to 'item':'A'. But, "I need all the documents that have the 'item' : 'A', along with the minimum price of all such items.". I want to print the relevant documents as well as the minimum price. Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: I have added an aggregation to get the documents with the minimum price.

Comment: Im so sorry for not adding the example earlier and I see it has created a lot of confusion. Please have a look at the added explanation. Thanks a lot for your help!.

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregationQuery =
   [ {
       $match : { item: 'A' }
     }
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$item",
           minPrice: { $min: "$price" }
         }
     }
   ]
db.collection.aggregate(aggregationQuery)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Please have a look at my comment on the answer written by @prasad_